# American tentacle movie

Tags: story-identification

So this is a 90s or 80s film, about these people that have these strings like ramen noodles coming out of them. It's like a virus, the military even starts to help, but the base is overrun..  A scene I remember is one of them is being helped by an army guy on a helicopter, but the string things have already overrun the helicopter.

It would be amazing if someone could tell me what movie this is, I was very young when I saw this. I don't even remotely remember anything else but this.

Comment: Sounds like one of the _Invasion of the Body Snatchers_ remakes, probably the 1993 one.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/200359/movie-about-alien-vines-like-controlling-brain (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 4):

Sounds to me like [Body Snatchers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_Snatchers_(1993_film)), the Abel Ferrera 1993 remake of Invasion of the Body Snatchers with Gabrielle Anwar and Forest Whitaker. The 'ramen noodles' were part of the duplication process IIRC.

It's for rent on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmBAKSBhTL0), there's also a [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okW2UfLNaJc) on Youtube.