# Movie about Alien vines-like controlling brain

Tags: story-identification, movie

What movie has aliens form vines control human brains in a small town?

Especially, there is a scene in the bath tub of a girl with so many threads going to her head and body even; like really thin threads. Like the whole town was affected by those invasive mind controlling alien life form.

Comment: see also the original 1956 version (https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/212607/looking-for-sci-fi-movie-with-feeling-less-duplicates) or its 1978 remake (https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103217/sci-fi-horror-where-people-were-taken-over-by-aliens)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the 1993 adaptation of the classic Invasion of the Body Snatchers called [Body Snatchers](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106452/plotsummary?ref_=tt_stry_pl#synopsis).

There is a scene in a bath IIRC but can't post that here.  This adaptation is not set in a town per se but instead it is set on a remote military base in the US.

The OP remembers the vines correctly as can be seen in the picture of the movie poster below:
[image]